# BIRT report showing different data in HTML and other formats

Tags: html, pdf, report, birt

I am new to BIRT and facing an issue : The report is showing correct data on HTML page but in PDF and XLS formats, the data changes and is displayed incorrectly.

This was on a live system. But when I tried the same from Eclipse -> Run -> View Report -> As HTML and then from Eclipse -> Run -> View Report -> As PDF, the difference is evident there as well.

Any idea about what could be causing this? (Until I faced this issue, I was under the impression that BIRT converts HTML to PDF so data is going to be same only.)

Comment: No, BIRT does not convert HTML to PDF.